# converting a string to integer with python

Tags: python, string, timestamp

[Please take a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGShL.png)

I am taking values from an excel sheet values (Like  `1333263660`) that are time-stamps, so if I enter manually that number to this code:

```
     time1=time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y/ %H:%M:%S',time.gmtime(a))
     time1=time1.split('/')
     print(time1)
```

I will get `['04', '01', '2012', ' 07:01:00']` as a result, but since I have to take those values from the excel sheet using this code:

```
  filecsv=open('AMPdsR1_1min_A.csv',"r")
  readlines = filecsv.readlines()
  for line in readlines:
     Type = line
     ttype=Type.split(',')
     b=ttype[0]
     print(b)
```

By printing `b`, I will get the following:

```
1364734320
1364734380
1364734440.....
```

But I have to convert them to an integer, so I can apply to them the first code to convert them to real dates.

But! When I do:

```
  b=b.replace(" ","") ##hoping to get the integer form of 1333263660
  c=int(b)
```

The following error pops up:

`ValueError:invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'TimeStamp'`

...And if I try:

```
  b=b.replace(" ","")
  c=float(b)
```

I get the error:
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'TimeStamp'`

PS: If I was to do this...

```
c=type(b)
print(c)
```

I get: `>>>"class 'str'" as a type of b`

Can someone help me please, to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you get error here `b=b.replace(" ","")` or while converting to int in next line?

Comment: You have a string `"TimeStamp"` and wonder why you can't convert it to a number? Please add an example of your data to your post. My best guess is that it is the header (the first row in your file). You should also include the full traceback usually when asking for debugging help.

Comment: Also, a file with comma separated values is not an Excel workbook.

Comment: no i get an error when converting to int in the next line

Comment: i have added a screenshot of the data

Comment: You also parse the first line, which is obviously not an integer like Ilja said.

Comment: yes you are right i did not notice that. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Ilja Everilä, the reason why you can't convert to either int or float is the header title of the first column is included in the conversion "TimeStamp", a simple if statement will do:

```
filecsv=open('AMPdsR1_1min_A.csv',"r")
readlines = filecsv.readlines()
for line in deadlines:
 if "TimeStamp" not in line:
  Type = line
  ttype=Type.split(',')
  b=ttype[0]
  print(b)
```

Try this and let me know, thanks

Comment: You might want to add this as a comment to the question, not as an answer.

Comment: llja was right the first row in the file which includes the names of the columns was causing the problem. so i have solved the problem by excluding it.

Comment: You can keep the header and add the if statement which will take of the issue too.

Comment: @aBiologist Pretty sure you have 56 now.

Comment: @ThatOneRandomScrub Thanks a lot